# Fill specific values of a numpy array (master) with values from another numpy array (slave) from same index position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fill

I prepared a mini example for my question.
Assume we have a master numpy array

```
master = 
array([[-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 2,  2,  2, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 2,  2,  2, -1, -1, -1]])
```

Secondly we have a slave numpy array with the exact same shape:

```
slave=
array([[-1, -1, -1,  3,  3,  3],
       [-1, -1, -1,  3,  3,  3],
       [-1, -1, -1,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3]])
```

What I'm looking for is the following:
`result = fill master array with slave values where master = -1`

```
result=
array([[-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3]])
```

In my real world scenario I have dozens of arrays with more than 12 million values each and they all have nodata values on different places. I want to fill the master array with the other arrays, where master values are nodata.

I really searched and tried a lot, like extract boolean masks but I really do not know how to fill on the exact same index coordinates without iterating over all single cells.

Would be great if I get help from you...

Comment: `np.where(master==-1, slave, master)`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you very much... It's so easy... I tried a lot with boolean masks and np.put() or np.fill() ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
result = np.where(master == -1, slave, master)
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.where` can take arrays as arguments hence:

```
result = np.where(master == -1, slave, master)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
result = np.where(master==-1, slave, master)
```

output:

```
array([[-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1, -1,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3]])
```